# Is it possible to force the .NET F# compiler generate a CIL field in a module?

Tags: f#, cil

when I compile an F# module like

```
module internal Test =
  let testnum = 5
  let testfun = fun (s, p) -> System.Console.WriteLine(s, p)
```

the former member in the generated IL code becomes a property with a getter only returning the constant, and the latter is compiled into a bona fide function. Essentially, C# for the generated IL is similar to

```
internal static class Test {
  internal static int testnum { get { return 5; } }
  internal static void testfun(string s, object p) {
    System.Console.WriteLine(s, p);
  }
}
```

Is there any known way to force these be compiled into real CIL fields? As would be in

```
internal static class Test {
  internal static readonly int testnum = 5;
  internal static readonly FSharpFunc<Tuple<string, object>, Unit> testfun = 
     new SomeInternallyGeneratedClosure();
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I would prefer the second version,myself.

Comment: Just curious here: why does it make a difference to you what the compiler outputs?

Comment: @xxbbcc: A testing framework I am evaluating requires some things to be fields or assignable properties. Specifically, the `testfun` can be replaced for a unit test run ("shimmed") if it has the field form. For C# it works like a charm.

Comment: @kkm Ah, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Could you write `Test` as a class instead?

Comment: @MarkSeemann: yes, I think so. Is what I want possible with a class?

Comment: @MarkSeemann: Does not look like it does any good. `let` bindings can only be private: error FS0646: Multiple visibility attributes have been specified for this identifier. 'let' bindings in classes are always private, as are any 'let' bindings inside expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to declare a public field in F#, you need to use a [explicit field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd469494(v=vs.100).aspx) on a class declaration.

Let bindings in class declarations don't allow additional access modifiers and are private, so they cannot be used to create public fields.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to wrap my head around options here. A field is indeed generated, but it can only be private and cannot be immutable.